# How to access a string using a dynamic string name in android (similar to eval in javascript)?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to access string variables using dynamic names depending on what position my gallery is at. To get the value of a string using a fixed name I use the following which is fine (the string is called pic1info):

```
String strTest = getResources().getString(R.string.pic1info);
```

My strings are named pic1info, pic2info, pic3info etc and I want to replace the static definition of pic1info to include the position so pass the contents of the following string in place of pic1info above so that it returns a different string depending on the current position:

```
String strDynamicStringName= "pic" + position + "info";
```

In javascript the equivalent would be eval, i'm sure there's a simple way to do this but i can't work out how!

Thanks so much for your help as ever!

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no simple way to do that in Java, but you can create an array of ints, where each index represents the R-value of that string.

```
private static final int[] LOOKUP_TABLE = new int[] {
   R.string.pic1info,
   R.string.pic2info,
   R.string.pic3info,
   R.string.pic4info
};
```

Getting a string would then become:

```
String strTest = getResources().getString(LOOKUP_TABLE[position]);
```

Answer (score 13):

use this: [android.content.res.Resources.getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("pic" + position + "info", "string", getPackageName());
String strTest = getResources().getString(resID);
```

Comment: This answer is much slower, as it will require the use of reflection in Java. Be very careful using this method in production code.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Kaj's answer, you can also put a [String array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) in your XML file:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="picInfos">
        <item>value of pic1info goes here</item>
        <item>value of pic2info goes here</item>
        <item>value of pic3info goes here</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```